# Suspected Eclipse or Java error?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I'm currently programming a 3D application from scratch using Java. Though I think I've come across some sort of Eclipse error or Java error?

```
for (int x = 0; x < displayWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < displayHeight; y++) {
        if (temppixels1[x][y] == 1 || temppixels2[x][y] == 1 || temppixels3[x][y] == 1 || temppixels4[x][y] == 1) {
            pixels[x][y] = 1;
            System.out.println("y");
        }
    }
}
```

It's part of a quad class that renders pixels. Now the above code works fine. But when I try to print something to the screen like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < displayWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < displayHeight; y++) {
        System.out.println("y");
        if (temppixels1[x][y] == 1 || temppixels2[x][y] == 1 || temppixels3[x][y] == 1 || temppixels4[x][y] == 1) {
            pixels[x][y] = 1;
            System.out.println("y");
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't render the screen? If that `System.out.println` code line is anywhere else in that segment then it works fine. I was just debugging my program when I stumbled across this. I have absolutely no idea why it is doing this?

Here's an image:
[image]
[image]